# How to display all rows / records from a database table with pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, row

I have hundreds of records in a database table.

### Code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM booking_tbl");
                
echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Booking ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        </tr>";
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['booking_nmbr'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['name_title']." ".$row['sender']."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

        mysqli_close($con);
```

It show all the records from the table `booking_tbl`.

But **I want to break the results 25 per page.** How can I do that?

Comment: Try some tutorials [*like this*](http://www.otallu.com/tutorials/simple-php-mysql-pagination/#sthash.LOUmyqBF.dpbs) and [*this*](http://www.otallu.com/tutorials/simple-php-mysql-pagination/#sthash.LOUmyqBF.dpbs) and many others

Answer (score 1):

One easy way of doing this is by using the `limit` and `offset` keywords. `limit` controls the number of rows to show, and `offset` controls where the query starts. Obviously, they should be used together with the `order by` clause.

So, e.g., for the first page you'd use:

```
SELECT * FROM booking_tbl ORDER BY booking_nmbr LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

And for the second page:

```
SELECT * FROM booking_tbl ORDER BY booking_nmbr LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Just use the MySQL `LIMIT` clause. So your code like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM booking_tbl");
```

Just set it to this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM booking_tbl LIMIT 0,10");
```

That will set the query to get `10` records from an offset of `0` (meaning the first record).

The format is basically:

```
LIMIT offset, count
```

With `offset` being the actual offset of the record set that you will retrieve. And `count` being the record count.

So knowing that your next step is to set pagination by taking URL parameters and such to do something like this:

```
$offset = $_REQUEST['offset'];
$count= $_REQUEST['count'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM booking_tbl LIMIT $offset,$count");
```

I consider that pseudo code since it will work, but you should really do filtering on the `$_REQUEST` values, but the general concept is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interest to achieve this using Javascript then you can use javascript DataTable library.
http://datatables.net/

You will get pagination,search and some other features within your table with a very simple method.
Also, it is easy to implement and able to handle very large data.